# Weather API with date parameter

Tags: api, weather

I am looking for a weather api that I can query by latlng and date.  The date seems to be the hard part.  All the APIs seem to only return the weather at he current day and/or week.  I also need it to work worldwide and not just in the US.

Can anybody suggest one?  Ideally i'd like to use Google or Yahoo but i don't think they provide this functionality or at least it is not documented

Answer (score 3):

The [Forecast.io API](https://developer.forecast.io/docs/v2) provides exactly the functionality you require. You can query by coordinates and any time in the past and future. It's available globally wherever there are weather data sources.

Answer (score -1):

You might find some answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507441/best-weather-apis

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about querying by date but you can query the Wunderground Data Feed by latlong, see http://wiki.wunderground.com/index.php/API_-_XML for all the details.